# Capture Image from a webcam using VB .Net 4.0

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, webcam

I have found a bunch of applications that work really well. They are referenced all over the web and stackoverflow. But there is one issue with these. They work till .Net 3.5 but fail when trying to run with .Net 4.0

Is there a solution that is relevant with .Net 4.0 VB? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881858/how-to-get-web-cam-images-in-c

Comment: It would probably help if you could explain what exactly the problem is with the .net 3.5 examples? What breaks when you change the target framework to 4?

Comment: some specifics would help, like what fails, how it fails and what these well known "bunch of applications" are