# Open the camera on a MS Surface Pro 3 from vs2010 .net 4.5 Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

So, I am developing a custom winforms program in vs2010.  This program will be installed on MS Surface Pro 3's that we will ship out to our employee's in the field.  One part of the application required them to snap a photo of what they are looking at.  I would like to place a button in my winforms program that will open the surface Pro 3 camera.  Does any one know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Oh! i am developing this on my windows 7 machine using vs 2010 but I do have a test Surface I have been using.

Comment: Take a look at DirectShow, and this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881858/how-to-get-web-cam-images-in-c

Comment: My first bet would be Aforge.Video.DirectShow, as it seems to be a bit more friendly than DirectShow.NET, which is a one-to-one wrapper over the COM interfaces.

Comment: I am currently trying out Direct Show, and am able to view and open my camera, however i am unable to take a snap shot.  Does any one have any sample code to take a look at.  everything online I have found either is hard to understand or doesn't work.