# Capture Image using Microsoft LifeCam and C#

Tags: c#, webcam

I have a Microsoft LifeCam and I want to Capture image using C# and use the image inside my application.

I have checked [A previously asked question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3843183/1471381) but the link provided in first answer to [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencv/) looks to be invalid ( I get "FORBIDDEN" response ).

I want to know if there is any Sample that I can use to learn and capture Image from LifeCam? And also I need the **dll** (s) for this.

Does anyone have any experience in this case?

Comment: what about this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494202/how-to-capture-8mp-still-image-from-a-microsoft-lifecam-programatically

Comment: quite interesting topic +1

Comment: @Freelancer the main problem is all I have is the device itself, no sdk, no dll, no files and nothing. That is why I am looking for a code sample that contains the dll s and everything needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Sascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66907/sascha), [ESCAPI Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16010448/1471381) really helped, I used the ESCAPI.dll along with the C# wrapper to translate it to C# and it all went well.