# Just Capture image from Microsoft Lifecam

Tags: c#, webcam, video-capture

I've already searched a lot and [Asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16009821/1471381) about capturing image from LifeCam which always ends up to OpenCV or DirectShow. But what does Microsoft itself do in Lync?

I currently have Lync installed in my Windows 8 and lync is working well with my LifeCam, also Windows 8's Camera is detecting LifeCam and easily captures images.

All I need is to know which dll I should import and which function I should Call. It does not matter if I use an external dll or if the solution is not totally .net . I just want to make it done. I need images being captured with a button click. That's it.

Is there any easy way to just capture an image with a button click? I do not need any more functionality.

Comment: Is it a Windows 8 App?

Comment: @Sascha no it is a .net 4 winforms application that I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried [ESCAPI](http://sol.gfxile.net/escapi/index.html) a while back. It worked but wasn't easy. Unfortunately I have not useful samples. But this should work

Comment: Finally a different solution, thank god. Now can you tell me what function I need to call in C# to capture the image in my C# application?

Comment: doCapture is the C function. There is a wrapper around which should make it easier. I haven't found the wrapper using a short Google search. On the website there is a The API section which shows a short usage sample.

Comment: Thanks dear @Sascha, it really helped. I like this solution because it gives me what I want in a simple way, but OpenCV ... I'd rather not dream it even :) thanks