# How to connect two web cam's in window application?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to connect two webcam's in my application and display the two webcam's images in two picture box controls using c#.How can i do?

Comment: See similar Questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236249/simple-net-webcam-library ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233455/webcam-usage-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Trikks i connected 1 webcam,but i am unable to connect another to the same application..

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368.aspx (suggested by microsoft)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library (library for the above)

And a simple article :
 http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2007/12/21/WIADesktopLibrary.aspx

Comment: I think you need to cross check, I just checked, the links which I mentioned are opening.