# Is it possible to use a camera mode in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, camera, rotation, move

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Webcam usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233455/webcam-usage-in-c-sharp)

and if it is possible to create a camera with Windows Form using C#.

It is Crucial in Forms because it is for my school project..

If there isnt something like that is it possible to create such an effect?

Comment: you are going to have to explain what your question means.

Comment: What do you mean by camera?

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/93476-Programatically-Using-A-Webcam-In-C/

Comment: "is it possible to create such an effect", yes.... use a camera.

Answer (score 1):

AForge is a very easy to use library that can easily make use of a webcam in WinForms. I designed a small app for taking pictures with medical tablets last year and the whole executable weighed less than 1Mb, with the AForge library being the bulk of that.

http://www.aforgenet.com/

Check the sample applications that it comes with, there is one premade that has all the code you'll need. It's also a cool library to play with by itself.